# Update only matched records in keyed KDB+ table with Q

Tags: kdb

I have a keyed table (tableA), and I want to update it with changes from another keyed (tableB) table, but only with records where the key in tableB matches a key in tableA. In other words, I do not want any new records in tableA, I only want to update the ones that area already there. tableA will have some columns that don't exist in tableB, and I want to preserve the original values of those columns. For example, if tableA and tableB looked like this:

```
tableA:([lname:`Dent`Beeblebrox`Prefect; fname:`Arthur`Zaphod`Ford]; iq:98 42 126; age: 23 49 78)

lname      fname | iq  age
-----------------| -------
Dent       Arthur| 98  23
Beeblebrox Zaphod| 42  49
Prefect    Ford  | 126 78

tableB:([lname:`Dent`Dirk; fname:`Arthur`Gently]; iq:105 118) <-- no age column

lname fname | iq 
------------| ---
Dent  Arthur| 105
Dirk  Gently| 118
```

Then the desired outcome of the update would be:

```
lname      fname | iq  age
-----------------| -------
Dent       Arthur| 105 23    <-- iq updated, age left alone
Beeblebrox Zaphod| 42  49
Prefect    Ford  | 126 78

* Dirk Gently NOT added because he didn't exist in tableA
```

Very grateful if anyone can give me an efficient syntax for updating a table this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lj` is what you want here:

```
q)tableA lj tableB
lname      fname | iq  age
-----------------| -------
Dent       Arthur| 105 23
Beeblebrox Zaphod| 42  49
Prefect    Ford  | 126 78
```

Comment: Hah! I can't believe it was that simple. I actually tried that on my real data, but it through a `wsfull` error and crashed my KDB process so I assumed I was barking up the wrong tree. `lj` works perfectly for the simple example I posted here, but reliably crashes my process when there are around 10k records in each of tableA and tableB, with about 180 columns in each (mostly int columns), which doesn't seem like it should excessively tax KDB on a 16GB host machine. Any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: Suffice to say the 180 x 180 column alignment was a slightly contrived example I was doing with some test data - the final code I needed this for was actually about 20 columns mapped to to a 180 column table, and that worked perfectly with `lj` just as you described. Curious about the `wsfull` error still, but has no effect on my real world scenario or on the correctness of the answer so thanks very much!